# Using ANT properties in Jenkins build job

Tags: ant, properties, jenkins

I'm trying to `exec` a script from my ANT-task. This script does some svn-stuff and should then set the outputproperty `svndiff`:

```
<target name="svn-diff">
    <exec executable="/usr/local/rbenv/shims/ruby" outputproperty="svndiff">
        <arg line="${source.dir}/changeparse.rb" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

I want to use this `svndiff` property to send it via email in a jenkins post-build-step to some recipients, but i cannot seem to use it in Jenkins. The mails i receive from this only have `$svndiff` as content.

Don't know if this helps, but in the top of my ANT-script i declare this property with

```
<property name="svndiff" value=""/>
```

Another approach i did was to modify Jenkins' environment variable array, by declaring my property as `env.svndiff` and setting the outputproperty of the exec target respectivly but this didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems there is no solution for my problem, so i built a workarounded for it.

I put the output of my ruby script into a file, and send the file via email (as attachment) to a recipient list.