# How to pass variables from ANT to Jenkins job

Tags: ant, jenkins

I saw a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126797/using-ant-properties-in-jenkins-build-job) that wasn't answer.

I am running ANT command to find the most updated file in the SFTP server.

```
<loadresource property="newest.file">
            <concat>
                <fileset file="list.txt" />
            </concat>
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <replaceregex pattern="([0-9]{6})" replace="\1" />
                </tokenfilter>
                <sortfilter reverse="true" />
                <headfilter lines="1" />
            </filterchain>
        </loadresource>
```

I would like to use newest.file property in another build step in Jenkins.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to save the property into a file.

Then use [**EnvInject**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to load the property file as environment variables